# Java - Time Complexity O(N**2)

Tags: java, time-complexity

I'm practicing on Codility. There is an Easy Level question, yet I'm stuck on performance. The test result analysis marks this code as O(N**2), but obviously there are not any nested loops. Can anyone tell me why my code is O(N**2)?

```
public static int solution(int X, int[] A) {
    List<Integer> temp = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 1; i <= X; i++ ){
        temp.add(i);
    }

    int counter = 0;
    int res = -1;
    for (int i: A){
        if (temp.contains(i)) {
            temp.remove(new Integer(i));
        }
        if (temp.size() == 0){
            res= counter;
            break;
        }
        counter++;
    }

    if (temp.size() != 0){

        res = -1;
    }
    return res;
}
```

Comment: You may want to check the [documentation for `ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ArrayList.html#contains(java.lang.Object)): "[except for `add`, a]ll of the other operations run in linear time (roughly speaking)" You have calls to `contains` and `remove` *inside* a loop.

Comment: I think it's due to the use of `remove` and `contains`. At worst, they will cost a full traversal of the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The test result analysis marks this code as O(N**2), but obviously
> there are not any nested loops. Can anyone tell me why my code is
> O(N**2)?

Asymptotic complexity is not (just) about loop counting.  You have a loop over the elements of `A`, and within it you invoke `temp.contains()`, and conditionally `temp.remove()`.  For an `ArrayList`, the cost of each of these is proportional to the number of elements in `temp`.

Overall, then, if `N` is `A.length` then the asymptotic complexity of your method is O(X * N).  Codility's analysis seems not quite right,  but if `X` cannot be taken as bounded by a constant then your code nevertheless is more complex than `O(N)`.  If Codility performed an heuristic analysis that introduced an artificial relationship between `X` and `N`, then *subject to that functional relationship*, your method could indeed be O(N<sup>2</sup>).

---

You can definitely do better.  Your method appears to be computing the length of the smallest initial sub-array of `A` that contains all of the integers between 1 and `X`.  To do this efficiently, you do need some kind of mechanism to track what values have been seen, but containment in a `List` is an expensive choice for that.  Consider instead an array of `boolean` to track which specific values have been seen, and a separate count of how many have been seen:

```
boolean[] seen = new boolean[X + 1];
int numSeen = 0;
```

With that in hand, loop over the elements of `A`, and for each element `i` that is in the range 1 ... X, test `seen[i]` (costs O(1) per test).  If `true`, do nothing.  If `false`, set `seen[i]` to `true` (O(1)), increment `numSeen` (O(1)), and test whether numSeen has reached `X` (O(1)).  Return the number of elements that have to be examined before `numSeen` reaches `X`, or -1 if `numSeen` never does reach `X`.  (Details left as an exercise.)

With that, every loop iteration performs `O(1)` work regardless of any bound on `X`, and that `O(1)` work is in fact *cheap*, which is a different consideration.  Overall: O(N), and pretty efficient, too.

Answer (score 2):

That is because of the use of `contains`. `temp` is an `ArrayList`, and `contains` performs a linear lookup. Within a for loop, that will become *O(N<sup>2</sup>)*.

Comment: That conclusion depends on `X`, the initial length of `temp`, to be guaranteed to be proportional to `A.length`.  Without such a constraint, the asymptotic complexity could be either more or less, and all we can say for sure is O(X * N).

Answer (score 0):

The other loop is hidden in the remove method of `ArrayList`.  The remove method of `ArrayList` is O(N) because it has to shift the elements to fill the gap.

```
for (int i: A){   // ===> O(N)
        if (temp.contains(i)) {
            temp.remove(new Integer(i));  //===> O(N)
        }
        if (temp.size() == 0){
            res= counter;
            break;
        }
        counter++;
    }
```